# Zurb Ink Email not Formatted Properly in Gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, zurb-foundation, mandrill, zurb-ink

I am using a [Zurb Ink](http://zurb.com/ink/) template to send an email. When I view the email in [mailcatcher](http://mailcatcher.me/) (from the development server) everything looks fine, but when I receive an email from the production server (to my gmail account), all of the CSS styling is gone.

The CSS is all inline, and I am using the [basic template from Zurb](http://zurb.com/ink/downloads/templates/basic.html).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**I missed a step over at Zurb's site.**

After editing your template you need to run the code through the [CSS inliner](http://zurb.com/ink/inliner.php), before the email HTML is ready to send.

Note: You will need to add any ruby code (etc) to the email **AFTER** running it through the inliner, as it will be stripped out by the inliner.

Comment: You're right.  Gmail is known for stripping out CSS if it isn't inlined.  Not all email readers would have displayed this issue.

Comment: Zurb Ink needs to write this in massive letters on every page on the site. I missed this somehow!